# ImageIcon Source on Different Computers

Tags: java

I have the following code in my program:

```
final ImageIcon mapStart = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Damian\\Desktop\\Main Start.png");
```

How do I make it so that when someone downloads my source files that it will still work.

Thanks.

I've tried this:

```
final ImageIcon mapStart = new ImageIcon(http://i200.photobucket.com/albums/aa218/damiantheman1/MainStart.png);
```

but an error came up. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Either use a relative path (and place the image within a relative location to the your program) or embedded the image within your program and use `Class#getResource` to load the image from within the application context

For some more information take a look at [Retrieving Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html) and [Location-Independent Access to Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) and [`Class#getResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))

You may also like to have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) as an alternative to loading images via `ImageIcon`

Comment: What would be an example of a relative location? In the downloads folder? What would I put in after the "C:\\Users\\" though?

Comment: `new File("path/to/images");` <-- Note, no leading `"/"`, this path is relative to the execution context from which the program was launched...You could also use `./path/to/images` which basically means "from the current directory got to "path/to/images""

Comment: Can I use the URL method instead?

Comment: I've tried this: final ImageIcon mapStart = new ImageIcon(http://i200.photobucket.com/albums/aa218/damiantheman1/MainStart.png); but an error came up. Am I missing something here? I edited this into my main post.

Comment: `new ImageIcon(new URL("http://i200.photobucket.com/albums/aa218/damiantheman1/MainStart.png"))` would be what you are probably after. Note though, `ImageIcon` will start a background thread to download the image, so it may not be immediately available

Comment: yes that is what I need, but I get a unreported exception, Malformed URLException must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: Yep, you need to deal with the exception that `URL` throws, wrap it in a `try-catch`...would still recommend embedded in the resource and using `ImageIO` in either case...